# Use subquery results to use as FROM select

Tags: mysql

I would like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (multi-row results of table names);
```

The result of the sub query are table names that I must consult with a select to get column values. Example:

Subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(TableName) 
FROM EmployeeTables 
INNER JOIN EmployeeCenters ON IdJobCenter = '26534450930122996';
```

This return:

```
TableName
Z26534450930123003_2020
Z26534450930123001_2020
```

I need

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM Z26534450930123003_2020 
UNION 
  SELECT * 
 FROM Z26534450930123001_2020, [n]...
```

Comment: You need in dynamic SQL (prepared statement). https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html

Comment: you need a prepared startemnt a loop and fetch to build such and dynamic sql

Comment: @nbk He needs UNION - so he may generate one UNION query and execute it, no loop needed.

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function

Comment: Thanks, I will document about stored procedures.